# Angular CLI with in workspace not generating things to the right sub folder

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular CLI project using workspaces and I am having trouble getting the `ng g` command to put things in the right place.

Here is the basic folder structure:

[image: basic folder structure]

So I would expect things to go into `/projects/angular-app/src/app`, but when I run `ng g m jobs`, it puts it in `projects/angular-app/jobs/jobs` when I want it to be in `projects/angular-app/src/app/jobs/jobs`.

I believe this is the relevant part of my `angular.json`, but let me know if you need more:

```
"projects": {
    "angular-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/angular-app/src/app",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/angular-app/src",
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use "cd" command to enter into the folder you want and create a module. By default angular creates all files at the root folder.    Create jobs folder, cd into it and create a module in there.

Comment: Files can be exported manually by gicing to a path 
  "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputPath: ''some_path'

Answer (score 0):

According to a suggestion above, I am going to `cd` into a directory and run `ng g` there, thanks!

If any other answers are posted, I'll gladly accept them instead!